# Cassandra: get keyspace size

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Is it possible to determine Cassandra cluster size using DataStax driver?

I am aware about `nodetool cfstats` command, but this is not what I need. I need to this from my program code with no physical access to the cluster.

Any ideas or workarounds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those metrics are not available in the server metadata accessible by native protocol drivers.

They are accessible via JMX, which is what nodetool uses to get them. Presently you would need to integrate a JMX client in your application and query that interface. There has been [some discussion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7622) about exposing similar metrics in virtual tables, which would expose this data to CQL drivers.